# как прочитать классы и методы внутри dll написаной на .net через C#

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, dll, декомпиляция

Возможно этот вопрос ранее освещался....
я создаю библиотеку классов .net framework следующей структуры

```
public class1{
   метод1();
   метод2();
}
```

и собираю ее.
Далее я создаю консольное приложение и хочу написать функцию которая прочтет эту dll и выведит назнание класса и методов... пытаюсь хотя-бы считать все содержимое

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(pathAll, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
                }
            }
```

И разумеется я получаю бред. Подскажите, как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`Assembly.Load`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netcore-3.1)
2. [`Assembly.GetTypes`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Igor, спасибо, сейчас ознакомлюсь

Comment: спасибо Вам! данный класс полностью удовлетворил решению моей задачи!

Comment: @parabol Отлично. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathAll);

        Console.WriteLine(SampleAssembly.GetName());
        foreach (Type oType in SampleAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oType.Name);

            foreach(MemberInfo members in oType.GetMembers())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    " + members.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```